# Putting data base values into array shows error in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter

I am taking data from many tables. I want to display many objects in different places. I got the data from data base, but I want to put the data into an array for useful purpose, but it's not working.

This my controller code:

```
public function compare_by_business_sectors() {
    //print_r($this->input->post());exit;
    if ($this->input->post())
    {
        $solution_array = array();
        //print_r (json_encode($business_sectors)); exit;
        $business_sectors=$this->home_model->compare_business_sectors_data($this->input->post());
        $tab_child_id = "";
        $id="";
        foreach ($business_sectors as $key=>$sectors) {
            $solution_array[1]=$sectors->solution_name;
            $solution_array[2]=$sectors->description;
            $solution_array[3]=$sectors->vendor_name;
            $solution_array[4]=$sectors->video_presentation;
            $solution_array[5]=$sectors->start_free_trail;
            $solution_array[6]=$sectors->hardware_package;
            $solution_array[7]=$sectors->pos_market_rating;

            //$solution_array[$sectors->field_id] = $sectors->value;
            $id = "solution".$sectors->tab_child_id;
            if ($tab_child_id != $sectors->tab_child_id) {
                $id = array();
                $id[$sectors->field_id] = $sectors->title;
            }
            else if ($tab_child_id == $sectors->tab_child_id) {
                $id[$sectors->field_id] = $sectors->title;
            }
        }
        //$solution_array[$id]= $id;
    }

    print_r($id);
    //$this->load->view('compare_by_business_sectors.php');
}
```

This is my model code:

```
public function compare_business_sectors_data($sectorid) {
    $query = $this->db->select('solutions.*,solution_tabs_child_fields.field_id,solution_tabs_child_fields.tab_child_id,solution_tabs_child_fields.title')
            ->from('solutions')
            //->join('solutions', 'business_sector.sector_id = solutions.business_sector_id',"left")
            ->join('solution_features','solutions.entry_id  = solution_features.entry_id',"left")
            ->join('solution_tabs_child_fields','solution_features.field_id = solution_tabs_child_fields.field_id')
            ->where('solutions.business_sector_id', $sectorid['id'])
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
    //print_r($query->result());exit;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: you can use row_array(); on results on codeigniter it's should be more simple as do it yourself.

Comment: Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal offset type

Filename: controllers/home.php

Line Number: 131

Comment: Do u have title in both tables with same name?

Answer (score 0):

change it as follow and try.

```
   $id_string = "";
   $id_array = array();
        foreach ($business_sectors as $key=>$sectors) {
            $solution_array[1]=$sectors->solution_name;
            $solution_array[2]=$sectors->description;
            $solution_array[3]=$sectors->vendor_name;
            $solution_array[4]=$sectors->video_presentation;
            $solution_array[5]=$sectors->start_free_trail;
            $solution_array[6]=$sectors->hardware_package;
            $solution_array[7]=$sectors->pos_market_rating;


        //$solution_array[$sectors->field_id] = $sectors->value;
        $id_string = "solution".$sectors->tab_child_id;
        if ($tab_child_id != $sectors->tab_child_id) {
            $id[$sectors->field_id] = $sectors->title;
        }
        else if ($tab_child_id == $sectors->tab_child_id) {
            $id[$sectors->field_id] = $sectors->title;
        }
    }

print_r($id_string);
print_r($id_array);
```

First you are assigning string value to $id then, $id will convert to array only if first if() statement execute other wise it will not be a string. So to overcome from this keep $id_array before for loop and you can capture string in another variable.